# The well founded core of a solid $\operatorname{ZF}^-$-model obeys $\Sigma_0$-collection

Tags: set-theory

Let $\mathcal A = (A;E)$ be a model of $\operatorname{ZF}^-$ such that its well-founded core $\operatorname{wfc} (\mathcal A)$ (we also write $\operatorname{wfc}(\mathcal A)$ for its universe) is a transitive model with the true $\in$-relation. I'd like to see that $\operatorname{wfc}(\mathcal A)$ is a model of $\Sigma_0$-collection.
To this end fix $u,p_1, \ldots, p_n \in \operatorname{wfc}(\mathcal A)$ and a $\Sigma_0$ formula $\phi$ s.t.
$$
\operatorname{wfc} (\mathcal A) \models \forall x \in u\exists y \colon \phi(x,y,p_1, \ldots, p_n).
$$
As $\mathcal A$ is a model of $\operatorname{ZF}^-$ and $\phi$ is absolute between $\mathcal A$ and its well-founded core, there is some $v \in A$ s.t.
$$
\mathcal A \models \forall x \in u\exists y \in v \colon \phi(x,y,p_1, \ldots, p_n)
$$
and whose rank (as calculated in $\mathcal A$) is minimal with this property.

How do I argue that $v \in \operatorname{wfc}(\mathcal A)$?

Comment: You have one $\operatorname{wfp}$.

Comment: @Asaf Thanks, I corrected that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $v \not \in \operatorname{wfc}(\mathcal A)$. Then there is some $y_0 \in v \setminus \operatorname{wfc}(\mathcal A)$ and we have
$$
\mathcal A \models \operatorname{rank}(y) < \operatorname{rank}(y_0)
$$
for all $y \in \operatorname{wfc}(\mathcal A)$. As
$$
\operatorname{wfc} (\mathcal A) \models \forall x \in u \exists y \phi(x,y,p_1, \ldots, p_n)
$$
this yields
$$
\mathcal A \models \forall x \in u \exists y (\phi(x,y,p_1, \ldots, p_n) \wedge \operatorname{rank}(y) < \operatorname{rank}(y_0)).
$$
Using Collection, we may now fix some $v' \in A$ s.t.
$$
\mathcal A \models \forall x \in u \exists y \in v' (\phi(x,y,p_1, \ldots, p_n) \wedge \operatorname{rank}(y) < \operatorname{rank}(y_0)),
$$
which implies $\operatorname{rank}^{\mathcal A}(v') \le \operatorname{rank}^{\mathcal A}(y_0) < \operatorname{rank}^{\mathcal A}(v)$. Contradiction!